# Visual Studio 2010 error: identifier out of scope when trying to debug

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli

I am stepping through c++ code and I am seeing a bunch of stuff where it says the symbol is undefined.

The strangest one was a method that I put a break point in. I was a couple lines under the method signature and I added a watch to a String^ variable type in the method. The first one I could see the value. The second one in the method signature it said that it was undefined. What could cause this?

If I put the breakpoint on the first line I can see a value in string1, but string2 is undefined. The error message in the watch window is:

error: identifier 'string2' out of scope

Project is in debug mode.
Configuration Properties->C/C++->Optimization->Optimization = Disabled (/Od)

```
  System::String^ MyNameSpace::CodeXML(String^ string1, String^ string2)
{
    System::Diagnostics::Stopwatch ^ performance_timer = System::Diagnostics::Stopwatch::StartNew();

    if(System::String::IsNullOrEmpty(string1))
        return System::String::Empty;
    int iTimeLimit=500,flags=0;
    bool bDBGFilter=false;
    System::String^ abc = System::String::Empty;

    if (!System::String::IsNullOrEmpty(string2)) {

        System::IO::StringReader^ sr = gcnew System::IO::StringReader(string2);
        XPathDocument^ doc;
        try {
            doc = gcnew XPathDocument(sr);
        } catch (System::Xml::XmlException^) {
            throw_managed_exception("Bad parameters XML");
        }
        XPathNavigator^ root = doc->CreateNavigator();

        if (XPathNavigator^ nav = root->SelectSingleNode("XXX/A"))
            if(!System::String::IsNullOrEmpty(nav->Value))
                iTimeLimit = nav->ValueAsInt;
        if (XPathNavigator^ nav = root->SelectSingleNode("XXX/B"))
            if(!System::String::IsNullOrEmpty(nav->Value))
                flags = nav->ValueAsInt;
        if (XPathNavigator^ nav = root->SelectSingleNode("XXX/C"))
            if(!System::String::IsNullOrEmpty(nav->Value))
                abc = nav->Value->Trim();
    }

    MyReport Report(EMPTY_STRING, iTimeLimit);
    ExtractedData^ ed = gcnew ExtractedData();  
    if(System::String::IsNullOrEmpty(abc))
        Report.SetHasSuperfilter(false);
    else
        Report.SetHasSuperfilter(true);

    Report.init();

    bool bRet = ExtractCodes(string1, abc, ed, Report);

    if (!bRet) 
        throw_managed_exception("ExtractCodes returned false");

    ostringstream dgn_strm;
    Report.summarize(dgn_strm);

    performance_timer->Stop();
    Report.add_performance_output("CodeXML", (long)performance_timer->ElapsedMilliseconds);

    String^ rv = OutputWriter::serialize(ed, Report);
    if (DBO d = "old") d << dgn_strm.str();

    MappingDiagnosticsSummaryLogger::IncDocCount();
    MappingDiagnosticsSummaryLogger::Log();

    return rv;
}
```

I stepped up a level in the call stack and I can see the value of the variable by holding my mouse over it. I just cannot see it in the function with the break point is.

```
virtual System::String^ ParentFunction(System::String^ string1, System::String^ string2) {
        return myObject->CodeXML(string1, string2);
    }
```

Comment: Please show us some code!

Comment: Could you please add the whole method if it's not 100 lines or so. And the line where you call this method. And tell us what mode you compiled in (make sure it's debug to avoid optimisations).

Comment: Without tracing the variable all the way back to its roots (I'll assume it wasn't a hard coded string) there isn't much of a way to see where it falls out of scope. If you trace it all the way back using breakpoints though you'll have a good chance of seeing where the problem is though. Good luck!

Comment: An MSDN search for `"out of scope"`gives no such error message, so I bet instead of posting the actual error, you paraphrased it. Also, you can't seem to decide whether your variable is named `string2`or `String2`. Remember C++/CLI is a case-sensitive language.